# How does a pneumatic siren produce alternating compression and rarefaction?

Tags: acoustics

A pneumatic siren operates by "chopping up" a compressed air source to produce high frequency pulses of high pressure air. If we set atmospheric pressure as O, and the guage pressure of the compressed air source as p, then the guage pressure output of the siren should look like a square wave between 0 and p. I.e, the guage pressure will never be negative.

However, when the sound reaches our ears, it will be a regular sound wave with both compression and rarefaction. That is, a waveform between a negative and a positive guage pressure, centred at zero.

How does this happen? How is the "DC offset" of the siren's output removed? How does the first rarefaction occur?

Comment: Our ears are sensitive to pressure alterations (well to static pressure too, like when diving or going in high altitudes, but is not perceived as sound), which the siren **does** provide. The fact that it is not zero-centred doesn't mean it won't be perceived as sound. If you think about your question is like asking: "how can we hear since sound is deviations from a DC pressure - which is the atmospheric pressure"? It is the same thing as going to higher or lower altitudes where you actually impose a DC compared to the atmosphere at the altitude you are now. You still perceive sound.

Comment: So there is no rarefaction at all relative to atmospheric pressure? This conflicts with Niels' answer :/

Comment: I mentioned that the siren *does* provide pressure alterations, which means that produces compressions and rarefactions. What might be confusing is that I focused on the reception side, which is: you perceive sound $\rightarrow$ the siren produces sound $\rightarrow$ there are compressions and rarefaction relative the DC atmospheric pressure, whatever that may be. Niels, described the procedure with which these compressions and rarefactions are produced. Apologies if this complicated things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compressed-air chopper siren produces rarefaction waves as follows. When the rotating chopper holes are lined up with the fixed holes in the plate behind it, air rushes out through the holes and a compression wave is created. The rushing air contains inertia and when the holes close up, the burst of air wants to continue departing the disc system- but there is no net airflow out the holes to allow that, so the pressure between the disc and the departing compression wave goes briefly subatmospheric and a rarefaction wave then follows the conpression wave away into the air.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to calculate the waveform of this rarefaction?

Comment: within a few wavelengths of the source, it is nearly sinusoidal.

Comment: Sinusoidal for the square wave pressure source assumed in my question? Or always sinusoidal? My understanding was that rotary disk sirens approximate a triangle wave....